# JavaScript: how can I tweak this function to return all the results from the async functions in order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have a function that takes an array of async/sync functions and invoke each of them **sequentially** (as opposed to in parallel) in the same order as the input is passed.

For example:

```js
const sleep = (delay) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, delay))

const fn1 = async () => {
  await sleep(2000)
  console.log('fn1')
  return 'fn1'
}

const fn2 = async () => {
  await sleep(3000)
  console.log('fn2')
  return 'fn2'
}

const fn3 = async () => {
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log('fn3')
  return 'fn3'
}

const fn4 = () => {
  console.log('fn4')
  return 'fn4'
}

function serializeAsyncFns(fns) {
  return fns.reduce(
    (promise, fn) => promise.then(() => fn()),
    Promise.resolve()
  )
}

serializeAsyncFns([fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4])

// fn1 -> fn2 -> f3 -> f4
```

But now the return value of `serializeAsyncFns` is a promise that resolves to the return value of the last function in the input list, which is `f4`. Is there a way to tweak this funciton so that the returned promise resolves to the an array of values of all the functions, in order of how they got passed.

In this case it would be `['fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3', 'fn4']`

`Promise.all` doesn't work here as it would fire all the promises in parallel.

Comment: easiest way is with a for loop and async/await

Answer (score 6, accepted):

easiest way is with a for loop and async/await

```
async function serializeAsyncFns(fns) {
  const result = [];
  for (const fn of fns) {
    result.push(await fn());
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

If, for some reason you can't use async/await for that function, this is what I used to do before async/await was a thing

```
const serializeAsyncFns = fns =>
    fns.reduce((promise, fn) =>
        promise.then(results => Promise.resolve(fn()).then(result => [...results, result])),
        Promise.resolve([])
    );
```

Comment: The problem with the second code is that, if `fn` is not async, it will fail. You should wrap it with `Promise.resolve(fn())`